# Most efficient way of storing and updating data points / tables / csv tables in a table or database using python maybe SQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv, google-cloud-platform

I'm just learning as I go so I'm not really sure how to achieve what I want because I don't really know all the tools available at my disposal. I'm not sure how to ask this question but here goes.

I'm collecting data from various sensors/sources using google cloud compute engines.

The data is saved into csv files using python and pandas in the following format.

`Data1.csv`

```
Date         Data1
01-Jan-2000  122.1
...
09-Oct-2020  991.2
```

`Data2.csv`

```
Date         Data2
01-Jan-2000  101.1
...
09-Oct-2020  331.2
```

There's always a date column and there's always a Data column which is unique.

Sometimes the dates are daily, sometimes, they're weekly. Different data sets have different resolutions, frequencies, etc.

When I get the Data table, I always get the entire history because sometimes there might be changes in the historical data which need to be updated.

Right now, what I do is save all the csv files to the servers, and download them to my computer one by one and merge them using python using full outer joins.

```
df = pd.merge(Data1df,Data2df,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

I do this one by one in a loop until I create one big dataframe.

`bigframe.csv`

```
Date         Data1 Data2 ......
01-Jan-2000  122.1 101.1 .....
...
09-Oct-2020  991.2 331.2 ....
```

I need the bigframe table in one bigframe to work on.

When I update the data, which is on a daily basis, I redo all the steps above, one by one and recreate the bigframe table again.

I feel what I'm doing is very inefficient.

I need advice on how do make this more efficient and I have no idea where to start.

I have never used SQL or any kind of database before. Someone told me that it's a more efficient way of storing / manipulating / updating my data.

I want to know if I do everything that I was doing previously in the example I described.

Can a database be created where I can save dataframes/csv tables as columns in SQL tables?

Is there a way to add the csv data as a new column into an SQL table directly without saving it to my computer?

I'm also worried about different servers accessing the database and updating values at the same time, will there be a clash when 2 different "users" update the same table (but different columns, never the same column).

If the column exists is there a way to update that column easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of questions in one go. I will try to provide some answers.

1. Yes you can move directly from CSV to the database. You want [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) or in the `psql` client [\copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). `\copy` works from the point of view of the client user while `COPY` works from the server user. Though since you are using Python and presumably `psycopg2` you have access to [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#copy) in Python client. In either case you will need to `CREATE TABLE` for the data ahead of time. That leads to 2).
2. I would `CREATE TABLE` some holding tables for the daily data dumps. You would do `TRUNCATE` table and then `COPY` the entire new set into table. `COPY` is very fast. A caveat is that it is all or nothing, if there an error the entire `COPY` will roll back.
3. `CREATE TABLE` the final tables for the data. Then you could use joins to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` on the final tables using the information in the holding tables.

Comment: i updated my question, i forgot to ask, will there be a clash if more than one server tries to access the database? lets say one server is adding a column Data200952 and another is updating a column Data3, will one not be allowed to access the database? or will there be a queue of some sort

Comment: can I create an empty table to start with and slowly add columns , wait so you're saying that I have to create a separate table for EACH Data column or is that just a temporary table until it goes into the big table?

Comment: Not sure what server(s0 you are talking about? The database would just be one server.  The tables(s) you would create would depend on the nature of the data. If there is  a column(say the date) that ties the various data sets together then you could have a single table.

Comment: could you take a look at this question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380682/merge-multiple-csv-files-into-a-postgresql-database-using-python-pandas-and-sql

Comment: The question has been deleted.